# Find bucket in unordered_map from hash without a key

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I am using a std::unordered_map. I have a hash value and a way to determine if a given candidate key is the key that I am looking for, but I do not have an actual key. I want to look up the bucket corresponding to the hash value and go through each element in that bucket to see if it is the element that I am looking for. Unfortunately, the function std::unordered_map::bucket(x) requires x to be a key. Is there really no way to get a bucket from a hash value without first constructing a key?

**Details that you don't need to answer the question:** I could construct the key but in the common case of no collisions this will take longer than only checking if the single candidate I have found in the bucket is the right one. I have a low load factor so there are few collisions and even for a collision the full hash value is unlikely to match, so non-matches are quickly determined not to match. I care about this because I have determined with a profiler that key construction is taking a significant amount of time - there are many lookups and each lookup requires the construction of a key.

**Even more details that you really don't need to answer the question:** The keys are vectors of integers and my query is for the sum of two vectors. It is faster to check if a given vector V is the sum of two vectors A and B than to sum the two vectors into a third vector C=A+B and then compare C to V. I am able to determine the hash value of A+B without calculating the actual vector A+B because I store the hash values of these vectors and my hash function f has the property that f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B). So I just add the two stored hash values to get the hash value of the sum. I have already made sure to keep a spare vector around so that constructing a key does not require memory allocation but the code for adding the vectors is still taking a significant amount of time on its own.

Comment: Nope, can't be done.  If all you have is the hash, you can't really tell if you find the right one, so the problem is impossible, unless you have a key.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of your `unordered_map`? Specifically, what class do you use for the `Key`?

Comment: Why are you digging around in the buckets in the first place?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I thought his explanation was clear on that point.

Comment: @Bjarke: Are you _certain_ that it's faster to check if a vector is the sum of two vectors than to actually make the vector, even with using the "spare"?  I can't imagine why that would be.

Comment: @MooingDuck I believe that a hash value uniquely determines a bucket, so it should be possible to tell which bucket I want from the hash value. If we calculate C=A+B then we have to store C in memory, and when we check if C==V then we have to load C into the CPU's registers again. If we check A+B==V directly then that sequence of storing and loading C is avoided - we can calculate x=A[i]+B[i] and then immediately check x==V[i] while x is still stored in a CPU register.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The declaration is std::unordered_map<Monomial, MapToType, Hash, Equal, HashAllocator> where MapToType is a template parameter so I don't think you want me to expand all that out. Monomial contains a pointer to something whose layout is only determined at runtime, so I can't just show you what is it. In this context you can think of Monomial as containing a pointer to an array of ints where the last int is the hash value.

Comment: @BjarkeH.Roune Perfect - all you need is a constructor that makes a `Monomial` with a single element containing the desired hash key :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot avoid constructing *a key*, but you can avoid constructing the *entire key*.

For example, let's say that you have a key class `VectorKey` that encapsulates an `std::vector`, and caches the computed hash code. Further suppose that you provide implementations of `Hash` and `KeyEqual` that access the cached hash code off your `VectorKey`, and compare encapsulated vectors for equality. You can define a constructor of `VectorKey` that always constructs an empty `std::vector`, and sets the cached hash code to a value passed to the constructor:

```
class VectorKey{
    int cached_hash;
    std::vector<int> key;
public:
    VectorKey(const std::vector<int>& _key)
    :    key(_key)
    ,    cached_hash(calc_hash(_key)) {
    }
    // *** This is the centerpiece of the solution: *** 
    // *** this constructor effectively lets you access *** 
    // *** a bucket with nothing more than a hash code. *** 
    VectorKey(int hash)
    :    cached_hash(hash) {
    }
    // More code goes here for getting cached_hash
    // and also for checking equality
private:
    int calc_hash(const std::vector<int>& _key) {
         // calculate the hash code based on the vector
    }
};
```

With a key class like that, you can quickly find buckets by constructing a fake key:

```
size_type bucketIndex = myHashMap.bucket(VectorKey(precalculated_hash));
```