# Index to unordered map via tuple of data heavy objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<A, A>, B> map;`. I have a function that modifies such map

```
void modify(const A& a1, const A& a2)
{
    map[/* a1, a2 */].modify();
}
```

Now I am a bit concerned about unnecessary copies of `A`'s. Here are my attempts.

```
map[{a1, a2}].modify();
```

It looks clean, but it constructs temporary key (tuple) from copies of `a1`, `a2`.

```
map[std::tie(a1, a2)].modify();
```

This looks promising, because it constructs `std::tuple<const A&, const A&>` and passes that to map's `operator[]`. Signature of `operator[]` for my map is

```
B& operator[](const std::tuple<A, A>&)
B& operator[](std::tuple<A, A>&&)
```

Which doesn't match return type of `std::tie`, but it worked. So I look at a constructors of `std::tuple` and found converting constructors, which made me think, that copies are still made ([so I tested it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/869d1990e6195de7)).

Is there a way to query the map, **without** any unnecessary copies, and still preserve O(1) average lookup complexity?

Comment: C++11 is a must?

Comment: @StoryTeller I want to get this working in C++11, but I might be interested in other solutions as well.

Comment: Have you looked into either move semantics and or perfect forwarding? Here is a good article that explains it with the use of a normal map; but the concepts should still apply to an unordered map. http://bajamircea.github.io/coding/cpp/2016/04/07/move-forward.html

Comment: @FrancisCugler That's completely different case. In your linked blog, a key is passed by value, so you can move from it. In OP's question, parts of a key `a1` and `a2` are passed by const reference.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh okay; yeah I over looked that. Makes sense now.

Comment: @DanielLangr Then again; maybe he can rework the function to accept value in order to use move semantics or perfect forwarding, then again it depends on other parts of their code not show here too.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Sure, but if it accepted values, you would just move the copying to a different place. In case that arguments are lvalues, which I assume are. Otherwise, the solution would be easy :)

Comment: @DanielLangr That's why I liked this question and made it a favorite... It's a challenging one.

Comment: Will `a1` and `a2` always be of type `A`? Meaning that both parameters will always be of the same type such as `<int,int>`, `<float,float>`,`<T,T>`?

Comment: @FrancisCugler The signature of `modify` is set. I can't use neighter move nor perfect forwarding, since I have references.

Comment: You could use `std::tuple<A, A>*` as a key type a re-write the hash function  & operator accordingly. But beware of the lifetime of your object when querying your map (dangling pointer is a real danger)

Comment: @FrancisCugler We can assume, that yes, it will always be of same type, but I don't think it makes difference.

Comment: Purely theoretically you could compute hash directly from `a1` and `a2` and use key that can fake it's hash (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900012/1597714) answer). But this solution is going to be hacky and very likely not thread-safe.

Comment: @AMA Interesting solution, but I probably sacrifice a few copies, since this probably won't be bottleneck.

Comment: Do you have to use tuple?

Comment: If you do not use template, and your tuple is always a tuple of 2 element of the same type, why use a tuple at all ? Why not use a class directly ?

Comment: @Clonk That is what I was thinking. If `a1` & `a2` will always be of the same type; instead of using `tuple` use a single class template. `template<typename T> struct Pair { T t1, T t2 ... constructors etc. };` Use that instead of tuple and this way you might be able to use move semantics instead, but the OP did state that the modify function is `set`...

Comment: @FrancisCugler What would `pair` instead of `tuple` change? Or, `std::array<A,2>` as well. The whole problem is that you cannot move from const reference parameters that are bound to lvalues, which OP apparently does not want to modify.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yeah; I've been looking at that; and if the OP is not willing to change those facts then I don't think there really is a solution to what they want to achieve.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Maybe there is, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that you cannot avoid copying here. The whole problem boils down to something like this:

```
A x1;
std::tuple<A&> t1{x1};
const std::tuple<A>& t2{t1};
const std::tuple<A>& t3{std::tuple<A&>{x1}};
```

Both constructions of `t2` and `t3` invokes a copy constructor of `A` (live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MxTUb61kO3zL3HmD).

If you really care about performance and instances of `A` are expensive to copy, you can place them into some pool (e.g., `std::vector<A>`) and then put into your map only pointers to them (`std::unordered_map<std::tuple<A*,A*>,B>`).

---

**UPDATE**

Note that you can also design your own "tuple/pair" class that can be constructed either by values or by references. A very basic solution could look like:

```
struct construct_from_ref_tag { };

template <typename T> class ref_pair {
  public:
    ref_pair(T v1, T v2)
      : v1_(std::move(v1)), v2_(std::move(v2)), r1_(v1_), r2_(v2_) { }
    ref_pair(const T& r1, const T& r2, construct_from_ref_tag)
      : r1_(r1), r2_(r2) { }
    bool operator==(const ref_pair<T>& rhs) const {
      return ((r1_ == rhs.r1_) && (r2_ == rhs.r2_)); }
    size_t hash() const {
      return std::hash<T>{}(r1_) ^ std::hash<T>{}(r2_); }
  private:
    T v1_, v2_;
    const T& r1_;
    const T& r2_; 
};

namespace std {
  template <typename T> struct hash<ref_pair<T>> {
    size_t operator()(const ref_pair<T>& v) const { return v.hash(); }
  };
}
```

Its usage does not trigger any copy/move constructor during elements access in map:

```
std::unordered_map<ref_pair<A>, int> map;
map[ref_pair<A>(1, 2)] = 3;

A a1{1};
A a2{2};

std::cout << "before access" << std::endl;
map[ref_pair<A>(a1, a2, construct_from_ref_tag{})] += 1;
```

I don't like it much but it works. `T` must be default-constructible here and default constructor is supposed to be cheap. A live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/obSfPEJXn3Yr5oRw.

Comment: That's what I've came up with too, but was hoping I overlooked something.

Comment: @Zereges By the way, I would definitely profile to prove that the copying matters here at runtime first. Compilers are powerful and, unless copying involves e.g. dynamic memory allocations, it might be optimized away. We don't know the details since you didn't specify what `A` looks like.

Comment: But that was not point of the question. I merely asked whether it is possible to avoid the copy, from language point of view. What compiler does under the hood was not part of the question. That's why it didn't depend on what `A` actually is.

Comment: @Zereges I see, it was just a comment, maybe for another readers in the future.

Comment: @Zereges I just updated my answer by another solution. You might be interested...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid the copy. Instead of using tuples I written a basic template pair class and just substituted it in to your code from your site using move semantics, and this is what I've come up with:

```
template<typename T>
struct Pair {
    T t1;
    T t2;

    Pair<T>() : t1(), t2() {}
    Pair<T>( T a, T b ) : t1( std::move(a) ), t2( std::move(b) ) {}

    Pair<T>( const Pair<T>& p ) : t1( std::move( p.t1 ) ), t2( std::move( p.t2 ) ) {}
    Pair<T>( Pair<T>&& p ) : t1( std::move( p.t1 ) ), t2( std::move( p.t2 ) ) {}

    Pair<T>& operator=( const Pair<T>& p ) {
        t1 = std::move( p.t1 );
        t2 = std::move( p.t2 );
        return *this;
    }

    Pair<T>& operator=( Pair<T>&& p ) {
        t1 = std::move( p.t1 );
        t2 = std::move( p.t2 );
        return *this;
    }
};

struct verbose {
    explicit verbose( int val ) : val( val ) { std::cout << " default ctor\n"; }
    ~verbose() { std::cout << val << " dtor\n"; }

    verbose( const verbose& v ) : val( v.val ) { std::cout << val << " copy ctor\n"; }
    verbose( verbose&& v ) : val( v.val ) { std::cout << val << " move ctor\n"; }

    verbose& operator=( const verbose& v ) {
        val = v.val;
        std::cout << val << " copy assign\n";
        return *this;
    }
    verbose& operator=( verbose&& v ) {
        val = v.val;
        std::cout << val << " move assign " << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    int val;
};

struct verbose_hash {
    std::size_t operator()( const Pair<verbose>& v ) const {
        return std::hash<int>{}(std::move( v.t1 ).val ^ std::move( v.t2 ).val);
    }
};

struct verbose_eq {
    bool operator()( const Pair<verbose>& lhs, const Pair<verbose>& rhs ) const {
        return (std::move( lhs ).t1).val == (std::move( rhs ).t1).val &&
            (std::move( lhs ).t2).val == (std::move( rhs ).t2).val;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<Pair<verbose>, int, verbose_hash, verbose_eq> map;

void modify1( const verbose& v1, const verbose& v2 ) {
    map[{v1, v2}] = 1;
}

void modify2( const verbose& v1, const verbose& v2 ) {
    //map[std::tie(v1, v2)] = 1;  // won't work not using tuple
}

int main() { 

    map.emplace(  std::move( Pair<verbose>( verbose(1) , verbose(2) ) ), std::move( 0 ) );
    std::cout << "After emplace\n";

    verbose v1( 1 ), v2( 2 );
    std::cout << "Before lookup1\n";
    modify1( std::move(v1), std::move(v2) );
    std::cout << "Before dtors\n";

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
 default ctor
1 move ctor
2 move ctor
1 dtor
2 dtor
1 move ctor
2 move ctor
2 dtor
1 dtor
After emplace
 default ctor
 default ctor
Before lookup1
2 copy ctor        // copy
1 copy ctor        // copy
1 move ctor
2 move ctor
1 dtor
2 dtor
2 dtor
1 dtor
Before dtors
```

The code is using the move semantics but because the function is bound to an lvalue by const reference; you are not going to get away from the copies.